# Remove items at positions 1,2,4,8,16,.. from list

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, indexing

How would I go about removing every element with index 2^x in a list? 
I've tried using a for loop with a variable representing x increasing by 1 in every loop but this throws the out of range error.

e.g:

```
remove([0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1])
>>>[1,0,1,0,1]
```

Comment: only remove it if 2^x is smaller than the list length ....

Comment: Wait, in your example output are you using 1-based indexing, rather than Python's default 0-based indexing?

Comment: you probably have to loop backwards otherwise the positions of all the higher elements are changing.

Comment: at index 0,1,3,7,.. then

Comment: technically, 0 is not a power of 2...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's an irresistible temptation here to use the well-known "check if `x` is a power of 2" bit-manipulation trick -- `(x & (x - 1)) == 0`.

Since here you actually want to check `x + 1`, and in Python `== 0` can be subsumed in an implicit truthiness check...:

```
def remove(listarg):
    return [it for x, it in enumerate(listarg) if (x & (x+1))]
```

Pretty inscrutable, alas...!-)

Ah well, at least it's easy to check it works...:=_

```
>>> set(range(1,35)).difference(remove(range(1,35)))
{32, 1, 2, 4, 8, 16}
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably not the most efficient solution, but this is nice and simple:

```
import math

orig = [0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1]

max_power_of_2 = int(math.log(len(orig), 2))
# Only generate these up to the length of the list
powers_of_2 = set(2**n for n in range(max_power_of_2 + 1))

# Your example output implies you're using 1-based indexing,
#   which is why I'm adding 1 to the index here
cleaned = [item for index, item in enumerate(orig) 
           if not index + 1 in powers_of_2]

In [13]: cleaned
Out[13]: [1, 0, 1, 0, 1]
```

Comment: This is the sort of thing that makes me frustrated that Python list comprehensions don't have any sort of `while`/`until` support.  `itertools.takewhile` and friends just don't mix naturally with the usual (generally non-`lambda`-based) Pythonic idioms.

Comment: @JohnKugelman, thanks, I knew the list lookups would make this pretty inefficient, should have thought to use a set.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I'd do it:

```
from math import log

my_list  = [0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1]
new_list = [item for i,item in enumerate(my_list,1) if not log(i,2).is_integer()]
```

This yields `[1, 0, 1, 0, 1]`.

Comment: You inverted the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

Analytical approach:

```
from math import ceil, log

def remove(list_):
    """ Create new list with every element with index 2**x removed. """
    indices = set((2**i-1 for i in range(int(ceil(log(len(list_), 2)))+1)))
    return [elem for i, elem in enumerate(list_) if i not in indices]

print(remove([0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1]))  # --> [1, 0, 1, 0, 1]
```